# Fastlink edit and refresh links unable to connect

Tags: yodlee

Recently we got the fastlink urls(private urls and public urls) for add,edit refresh,

In these 3 operations add link working fine, but we face problem with edit and refresh url.

Error is : **oauth_error_problem=signature_invalid&oauth_error_code=407**

The signature generating process for the 3 operations same.
and here we are using private credentials for the 3 operations.

Please let me know required details for your testing.

Answer (score 0):

oauth_error_code=407 means the signature generated is incorrect, I would suggest you to check the details and see if no extra space is being provided while generating signature. As well please check the siteAccountId you would be providing is correct.

Here is the documentation [link](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Yodlee_FastLink_and_LAW_Guide/Yodlee_FastLink_Integration_Guide) which explains in detail and params needs to be used for generating Fast Link signature.